# Click on the link by comparing in Sikuli

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I have a text to be searched with its type defined in the excel sheet.Now When I search the text in the text field and click on search button, I am able to get the results.
for example
in excel sheet

text---type
abc----red
pqr----blue
cqd---orange

So the tricky part here is that I get 2-3 links for this Search with the type( there are different types for this search text).i.e. If I search abc in Search and I get results as

abc---orange
abc---red
abc---blue

I am stuck at the point where I have to click on the Search result ( which is a link) matching the type as mentioned in the excel sheet.i.e.
Sikuli should click the below result on webpage with:
abc---red

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet you've worked upon so far ?

Comment: Can you share your code? Then we can look if we can improve it for you.